# Edge cases in creating a custom linked List

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

While creating a linked list ( single linked list ) what are the edge cases that i should be covering?

Some of the cases that I have covered are :

a) No node
 (b) Only one node
 (c) Adding node at head/tail
 (d) Avoiding infinite loop while traversing the list
 (e) Avoiding memory leaks and dangling pointers

Answer (score 0):

Data-only functions for Node creation or removal:

```
public void appendNewNode(final int data) { /* data-only input */ }

public void deleteIfDataEquals(final int data) { /* data-only input */ }

public void prependNewNode(final int data) { /* data-only input */ }
```

Cycle detection:

```
public boolean hasCycle(final IntNode head) { /* edge scenario */ }
```

Index-based actions:

```
public Optional<IntNode> insertNewNodeAt(IntNode head, int data, int position) {
    //insertion and removal
}
```

Emptiness checks:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {/* for the positive case */ }

public boolean isNotEmpty() {/* and the negative case */ }
```

First and last removal:

```
public Optional<IntNode> removeFirstElement() {
    //Helpful when the list is backing a Stack
}

public Optional<IntNode> removeLastElement() {
    //Or the opposite for Queues
}
```

And a sometimes handy utility:

```
public int size() { /* very scenario-specific */ }
```